# Error while booting Fedora 17 from Live USB on Windows 8 HP Envy 4 1102tx

Tags: windows-8, multi-boot, fedora, liveusb

I am trying to run Fedora 17 using a Live USB on my recently bought HP Envy 4 1102tx which came with Windows 8 pre-installed. My system has a 500GB HDD and a 32GB SSD.

Every time I try to boot from USB, I get this error:

> Selected Boot Image Did Not Authenticate. Press `<Enter>` to continue.

I wrote the Fedora 17 64-bit image using LiveUSB Creator.

I also tried using the LiLi USB creator with Fedora 17's i686 version, but the machine did not boot from the USB drive with that version, either.

I also tried LiLi with Ubuntu 12.10 and 12.04, but again, booting did not happen.

I don't have an optical disk drive, so I can't install from a CD or DVD.

I want to dual-boot Fedora and Windows 8.

Is there any workaround available for this? Has anyone been successful with this dual boot setup?

Comment: I believe that is related to Secure Boot but I don't have an UEFI machine. You may check for it in the UEFI configuration utility and disable it, then it wouldn't check the signatures of what you want to boot. More info on Secure Boot here: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Unified_Extensible_Firmware_Interface#Secure_boot

Comment: Related: [Known problems with dual boot of Windows 8 and Fedora 17](http://superuser.com/questions/502969/known-problems-with-dual-boot-of-windows-8-and-fedora-17)